# Sonata User Bundle custom batch action

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, sonata-user-bundle

so as the title suggests, I need to  add custom batch action to `SonataUserBundle`.

With this action, the operator can send a message to all of the users (or selected ones). Therefore it needs to extend `SonataAdminBundle` in order to be able to add a custom view for this action.

The problem is, `ApplicationSonataUserBundle.php` is overriding `SonataUserBundle`:

```
class ApplicationSonataUserBundle extends Bundle
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'SonataUserBundle';
    }
}
```

and if I change it, it will break the Bundle.

Is there any solutions that I can add this batch action to the bundle?

Comment: > Therefore it needs to extend SonataAdminBundle in order to be able to add a custom view for this action.

Are you sure about this? I fail to see what the logical link is.

Comment: Yeah, unless it shows `Action... is not callable`

Comment: If you see this message, you just need to create the action, just like any other Symfony action.

Comment: Yeah, I did that before, in other bundles, but its not working on user bundle

Comment: You launch a batch action from a controller? why don't you use a Command?

Comment: What do you mean by a command?

Comment: I use batch actions in my project, and I don't need to extend the admin bundle. I don't know why you would think that.

Comment: Unfortunately thats what sonata shows me, I did it one more time exactly as the documentation says. And the problem was on that line (overriding)

Comment: @AienSaidi please add more code documentation about what you have done so far. The description is to generic: e.g. what do you mean by **the operator can send a message to all of the users (or selected ones)** ? provide as much info as possible.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is editing the sonata_user config to use you own Controller instead of the default Sonata Admin CRUD Controller.

So in your config.yml add the following:

```
sonata_user:
    admin:           
        user:
            controller:     MyAppMyBundle:UserAdmin
```

And create your own controller that extend CRUDController

```
namespace MyApp\MyBundle\Controller;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController as Controller;

class UserAdminController extends Controller
{
}
```

now you can add your own batch actions like this

```
class UserAdminController extends Controller
{
   public function batchActionSendMail(ProxyQueryInterface $selectedModelQuery) 
   {      
      $selectedModels = $selectedModelQuery->execute();

      // Your stuff here

      return new RedirectResponse($this->admin->generateUrl('list', $this->admin->getFilterParameters()));
   }
}
```

Hope it will help someone :)